# ffmpeg: concat filter does not work

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, concatenation

I'm trying to concat multiple (Proof of concept: 2) mp3 files using ffmpeg and the concat filter with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i "file1.mp3" -i "file2.mp3" -filter_complex [0:a:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:a=1[outa] -map [outa] out.mp3
```

ffmpeg reads both inputs successfully, I guess:

```
Input #0, mp3 [...]
Metadata: [...]
Duration: 00:00:13.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 423 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 650x677 [SAR 72:72 DAR 650:677], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Metadata:
      comment         : Other
[mp3 @ 0x7fadbc81a000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, [...]
Metadata: [...]
Duration: 00:06:58.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 199 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #1:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 650x677 [SAR 72:72 DAR 650:677], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      comment         : Other
```

But then fails with:

```
Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:a:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:a=1[outa] matches no streams.
```

Any ideas? Ffmpeg seems to read both streams, so I don't know what's wrong. I also tried `[0:0][1:0]` instead of `[0:a:0][1:a:0]`, giving the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

The concat filter needs to set three variables, n, v and a. Default value of v is 1 but you need to set it to 0. So, `concat=n=2:v=0:a=1`

Comment: You beat me to it. This is the relevant link to support your answer: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot so far. Yes, I've read that page beforehand, but didn't know about default values. I'll check that as soon as I find the time!